# Cannot compile function with jit with function that takes *args parameters

Tags: python, numba

I am trying to compile a function that takes in a numpy array and a tuple
of parameters of the form *arg using numba.

```py
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def myfunc(t, *p):
    val = 0
    for j in range(0, len(p), 2):
        val += p[j]*np.exp(-p[j+1]*t)
    return val

T = np.arange(12)
pars = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
mfunc = myfunc(T, *pars)
```

However I get this result

```py
In [1]: run numba_test.py                                                                                                                                                                  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)                                                                                                                
~/Programs/my-python/numba_test.py in <module>                                                                                                                                             
     12                                                                                                                                                                                    
     13 T = np.arange(12)                                                                                                                                                                  
---> 14 mfunc = myfunc(T, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)                                                                                                                                              

...
...                                                                                                                                                                                   
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)                                                                                                                    
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function iadd>) with argument(s) of type(s): (Literal[int](0), array(float64, 1d, C))                                                                    
Known signatures:                                                                                                                                                                          
 * (int64, int64) -> int64                                                                                                                                                                 
 * (int64, uint64) -> int64                                                                                                                                                                
 * (uint64, int64) -> int64                                                                                                                                                                
 * (uint64, uint64) -> uint64                                                                                                                                                              
 * (float32, float32) -> float32                                                                                                                                                           
 * (float64, float64) -> float64                                                                                                                                                           
 * (complex64, complex64) -> complex64                                                                                                                                                     
 * (complex128, complex128) -> complex128                                                                                                                                                  
 * parameterized                                                                                                                                                                           
In definition 0:                                                                                                                                                                           
    All templates rejected with literals.                                                                                                                                                  
...
...                                                                                                                                                                         
    All templates rejected without literals.                                                                                                                                               
This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.                                                                                   
[1] During: typing of intrinsic-call at /home/cshugert/Programs/my-python/numba_test.py (9)                                                                                                

File "numba_test.py", line 9:                                                                                                                                                              
def myfunc(t, *p):                                                                                                                                                                         
    <source elided>                                                                                                                                                                        
    for j in range(0, len(p), 2):                                                                                                                                                          
        val += p[j]*np.exp(-p[j+1]*t)                                                                                                                                                      
        ^
```

Numba does support working with tuples so I figured that there could be 
some signature I can add in the jit compiler. However, I am not sure 
exactly what to put there. Could it be the case that numba compilers 
cannot handle functions with *args as parameters? Is there anything I can do so that my function will be able to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see the error message again

```
TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)                                                                                                                    
Invalid use of Function(<built-in function iadd>) with argument(s)
 of type(s): (Literal[int](0), array(float64, 1d, C))                                                                    
Known signatures:                                                                                                                                                                          
 * (int64, int64) -> int64                                                                                                                                                                 
 * (int64, uint64) -> int64                                                                                                                                                                
 * (uint64, int64) -> int64                                                                                                                                                                
 * (uint64, uint64) -> uint64                                                                                                                                                              
 * (float32, float32) -> float32                                                                                                                                                           
 * (float64, float64) -> float64                                                                                                                                                           
 * (complex64, complex64) -> complex64                                                                                                                                                     
 * (complex128, complex128) -> complex128                                                                                                                                                  
 * parameterized
```

The error is for `<built-in function iadd>`, which is `+`.If you look at the error, it is not due to passing of `*args` but due to the following statement :

```
val += p[j]*np.exp(-p[j+1]*t)
```

Basically of all the compatible types for `+` mentioned, it does not support adding `integer` to an `array`(See the error message and known signatures for more info).

You can fix this, by setting `val` as an array of zeros using `np.zeros` (see doc [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html)).

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@nb.njit
def myfunc(t, *p):
    val = np.zeros(12) #<------------ Set it as an array of zeros
    for j in range(0, len(p), 2):
        val += p[j]*np.exp(-p[j+1]*t)
    return val

T = np.arange(12)
pars = (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0)
mfunc_val = myfunc(T, *pars)
```

You can view the code here in [this Google Colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Fx3wlqJ8baCPm82RyZnRKNbz6ZIPAr5z#scrollTo=B6k-TlxD4ud5).